# Matlab: Latin Hypercube

Tags: matlab, sampling

Is there a way to create a Latin Hypercube from a particular set of data? I have `d(1,:) = 3*t +0.00167*randn(1,1000);`. Is there a way for me to create a Latin Hypercube from the elements in `d(1,:)`?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An edit of the `lhsnorm` function can probably answer your question.

In matlab : `edit lhsnorm` :

```
function [X,z] = lhsnorm(mu,sigma,n,dosmooth)
%LHSNORM Generate a latin hypercube sample with a normal distribution
%   X=LHSNORM(MU,SIGMA,N) generates a latin hypercube sample X of size
%   N from the multivariate normal distribution with mean vector MU
%   and covariance matrix SIGMA.  X is similar to a random sample from
%   the multivariate normal distribution, but the marginal distribution
%   of each column is adjusted so that its sample marginal distribution
%   is close to its theoretical normal distribution.
%
%   X=LHSNORM(MU,SIGMA,N,'ONOFF') controls the amount of smoothing in the
%   sample.  If 'ONOFF' is 'off', each column has points equally spaced
%   on the probability scale.  In other words, each column is a permutation
%   of the values G(.5/N), G(1.5/N), ..., G(1-.5/N) where G is the inverse
%   normal cumulative distribution for that column''s marginal distribution.
%   If 'ONOFF' is 'on' (the default), each column has points uniformly
%   distributed on the probability scale.  For example, in place of
%   0.5/N we use a value having a uniform distribution on the                  
%   interval (0/N,1/N).
%
%   [X,Z]=LHSNORM(...) also returns Z, the original multivariate normal
%   sample before the marginals are adjusted to obtain X.
%
%   See also LHSDESIGN, MVNRND.

%   Reference:  Stein, M. L. (1987). Large sample properties of simulations
%   using Latin hypercube sampling. Technometrics, 29, 143-151. Correction,
%   32, 367.

%   Copyright 1993-2010 The MathWorks, Inc.
%   $Revision: 1.1.8.1 $  $Date: 2010/03/16 00:15:10 $

% Generate a random sample with a specified distribution and
% correlation structure -- in this case multivariate normal
z = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,n);

% Find the ranks of each column
p = length(mu);
x = zeros(size(z),class(z));
for i=1:p
   x(:,i) = rank(z(:,i));
end

% Get gridded or smoothed-out values on the unit interval
if (nargin<4) || isequal(dosmooth,'on')
   x = x - rand(size(x));
else
   x = x - 0.5;
end
x = x / n;

% Transform each column back to the desired marginal distribution,
% maintaining the ranks (and therefore rank correlations) from the
% original random sample
for i=1:p
   x(:,i) = norminv(x(:,i),mu(i), sqrt(sigma(i,i)));
end
X = x;

% -----------------------
function r=rank(x)

% Similar to tiedrank, but no adjustment for ties here
[sx, rowidx] = sort(x);
r(rowidx) = 1:length(x);
r = r(:);
```

In your case you already have your distribution `z` in the code above and you also have `mu`, `sigma` and 'n' (the size of your distribution), just replace them and you should be able to create your Latin Hypercube.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that I could use `lhsnorm(3*t, 0.00167 ,1000);` to give me a Latin Hypercube sample from the Normal Distribution. However, I don't know how to edit `lhsnorm` if I already have a normally distributed set of data such as that in `d(1,:)` that I mentioned above, and if I want to sample from that.

Comment: Thanks. I've made changes to the above code as follows below. I'm trying to accept a Normal Distribution now and create a Latin Hypercube for that, as I will need to create several Latin Hypercube for my Normal Distributions. However, the values I get in the end do not make sense.                                               `function [X] = lhsnorm_sid(z,dosmooth)              [muhat,sigmahat] = normfit(z);

z = z';
% Find the ranks of each column
p = length(muhat);
x = zeros(size(z),class(z));
s = size(z);
n = s(1,1);`

Comment: Even if I use `lhsnorm(3*60/800,0.00167,1000)` and change `z` I still get a problem with the outputs

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in matlab for the creation of latin hypercube samples: [`lhsdesign`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/lhsdesign.html)(which lets you specifiy your hypercube) or [`lhsnorm`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/lhsnorm.html)(which uses a normal distributed one) . both are found in the statistics toolbox.

Comment: Thanks. I did come across this. I am just unable to understand how to use it for my particular case.